# MVC 3 inject Controllers with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I can't seem to find an example of injecting controllers directly from a seperate project. Previously in Spring.net I would add the following to the Global.asax

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new SpringFactory);
```

and then simply add the entry to the xml
    <object name="Shared" type="..."/>

Could someone please outline the steps I need to take to accomplish this with the latest version of Ninject and MVC3? or a link to an example?

Addtionally I was wanting to do something similair with the Views (put them in a seperate project), can Ninject help me with this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `Ninject.Mvc3` package? It will set up everything for you: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ninject.MVC3.

Install it by typing: `Install-Package Ninject.Mvc3` in the Package Manager Console. It will add a file under the App_Start folder, there you can modify what you want to inject.

For the View part Ninject can help you if you have implemented your own `IViewPageActivator` that you inject. But why do you want to have your views in a separate project? The views belongs to the web application and should be located in the web application project.

Comment: Thanks. So I don't actually need to do anything once the package is installed.. it just finds the controller? I have two websites that have a load of views which are identical (and will always be) so makes sense to share them.

Comment: If you hame something that your controllers depends on you must update tell NInject that you depend on it. And you do that in the class that is created in the App_Start folder. Also, start accepting answers and vote for questions that helps you. Otherwise you will get less answers.

Answer (score 2):

Read the Ninject.MVC documentation: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

Comment: Why would you do it your self when it is automated using NuGet?

Comment: If you had read the documentation to the end you would see that both ways are described and not just the manual way and neither is favorized. The manual way is kept for backwards compatibility.